# How can I solve this lexographical sorting question from codeforces.com?

Tags: string

Little Petya loves presents. His mum bought him two strings of the same size for his birthday. The strings consist of uppercase and lowercase Latin letters. Now Petya wants to compare those two strings lexicographically. The letters' case does not matter, that is an uppercase letter is considered equivalent to the corresponding lowercase letter. Help Petya perform the comparison.
Input

Each of the first two lines contains a bought string. The strings' lengths range from 1 to 100 inclusive. It is guaranteed that the strings are of the same length and also consist of uppercase and lowercase Latin letters.
Output

If the first string is less than the second one, print "-1". If the second string is less than the first one, print "1". If the strings are equal, print "0". Note that the letters' case is not taken into consideration when the strings are compared.
Examples
Input
Copy

aaaa
aaaA

Output
Copy

0

Input
Copy

abs
Abz

Output
Copy

-1

Input
Copy

abcdefg
AbCdEfF

Output
Copy

1

My code

```
a = input()
b = input()
a = sorted(a.lower())
b = sorted(b.lower())
if a == b:
    print("0")
elif a > b:
    print('1')
elif a < b:
    print('-1')
```

in my code why do i have to remove sort() function

Comment: By using `sorted` you reorder the characters, so `'ba'` will be converted to `'ab'`.

Comment: in my code i have already used that function but still it fails on test case 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to sort the strings otherwise you will change the question itself.
You can do this

```
a = input()
b = input()
a = a.lower()
b = b.lower()
if a == b:
    print("0")
elif a > b:
    print('1')
elif a < b:
    print('-1')
```

Comment: Thanks @Prakhar Gupta for the solution but why wont it work if the strings are sorted can you explain a little more please.

Comment: @Ashish Consider s1='bcd' and s2='da' . s1 is lexographically lesser than s2 but after sorting, s1 becomes 'bcd' and s2 becomes 'ad' in which s2 is smaller which will give incorrect result.

Comment: okay i got that now thanks a lot @Prakhar